# SwipeRefreshLayout in MotionLayout with Recyclerview ignores click events

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-motionlayout

I have the following structure:

```
MotionLayout --> SwipeRefreshLayout --> RecyclerView
```

Everything works correctly except that items in the RecyclerView are not clickable. They are only clickable when the SwipeRefreshLayout is refreshing.

How can I fix this?

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: could you paste the java code?

Comment: What java code do you mean? This is mostly defined in XML as a Layout and a corresponding MotionScene

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `setOnClickListener` directly in the adapter.